# Spark: joining multiple derived dataframe of small sized to base large dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Using PySpark I am generating multiple dataframes(around 800 in number of each sized around 500 MB) using group by aggregation operation on base dataframe(of size ~700 GB).

Can any one suggest me what is the best approach to join back derived dataframes to the base dataframe.

Here is the representation of the code:

```
df_core = spark.read.parquet("s3://S3CompletePath”)
df_core_partitioned = df_core.repartition(3600,"symbol")#Persisted in disk of size 700 GB

def Merge_or_Write(factor_names = None, factor = None, df_features= None, df_tmp = None, joinOnly = False):
   if(joinOnly):
        if(df_features is None):
            df_features = df_tmp
        elif(df_tmp is not None):
            df_features = df_features.join(df_tmp,on = ["symbol","hour","minute"], how = "outer")
        if(df_features is not None):
            fname = "hdfs:///path”
            df_features.write.parquet(fname,mode="overwrite")#For each query file written to HDFS is of 500 MB
            df_features=None

def feature_calculation(sngl_query):
    df_filtered = df_core_partitioned.filter(sngl_query[1])
    global df_features
    #Feature1 ##############################
    if (re.search(r"searchString1", sngl_query[0]) is None):
        df_tmp = df_filtered.groupBy(["symbol","hour","minute","kind"],2).agg(fun.sum(df_filtered.volume).alias("volume"))
        #some more transformation, groupby on df_tmp
        df_features = Merge_or_Write(sngl_query[0],df_features,df_tmp,joinOnly = True)  
    #Similar to Feature 1 for another 4 more features
df_features = Merge_or_Write(sngl_query[0],df_features,df_tmp,joinOnly = True)

df_features=None
list_queries = [(“qr1”,” query1”), (“qr2”,” query2”), (“qr3”,” query3”)]#Total 786 queries
for sngl_query in list_queries:
    feature_calculation(sngl_query)
```

Comment: do you have code snippet/examples  .Your question content should be completely verifiable.see  [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what have you tried?  (join method?)

Comment: @tbone As of for each query i am saving intermediate individual query results(~500MB each)to EMR HDFS & then trying to combine all of the 786 results from HDFS before merging them to main dataframe that is persisted.But it is very slow as for every action of writing result to HDFS Spark try to read from persisted dataframe of size ~700 GB which takes 6-7 mins.So alternately i am considering to write group of queries & other time goes on joining results.Once all groups are written to HDFS, one by one join them to base dataframe that is persisted.Please let me know if you have  better suggestion